# Embed external URL into SSRS report

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2019

I am currently using SQL Server 2019.

I read in earlier editions of SSRS that you were not able to embed external web links into a SSRS report, it this still the case?

I currently have 4 separate KPI screen URL's written by our Group IT department and I would like to have all 4 KPI's on one screen so I though I would embed these into one SSRS Report.

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean you want to embed external content into a report (like in an iframe) or do you mean you want to add clickable links to a report that open external content? The latter is certainly supported and always has been, not sure about embedding external content though

Comment: I mean embedding external content not created by SSRS.  The reports are shown through a URL on our network, I do not know what they were originally written in.  I want the report to show straight away without having to click on any links.

Comment: I don't think that is possible, SSRS only has limited HTML support. The typical way to do this would be to create a web page that embeds the SSRS report plus your KPI parts, rather then the other way around. Only option might be to render the KPI's as images externally and then you can add images to the report that point to the external image's URL

Answer (score 1):

> I read in earlier editions of SSRS that you were not able to embed external web links into a SSRS report, it this still the case?

Where did you read that?  It's never been true.  There's even a doc page on how to do it: [Add a hyperlink to a URL in a paginated report (Report Builder)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/add-a-hyperlink-to-a-url-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: I am wanting the 4 separate KPI links to appear within the SSRS frame set, not just visible hyper links that you have to click on which then opens a separate window

Comment: You want to embed an IFrame inside the report?  No that's not possible.  You can embed an Image from a remote URL, but not a whole web page.